# $P(x,y)$ means that for given $x$ and $y$, the property $P(x,y)$ is true

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

$P(x,y)$ means that for given $x$ and $y$, the property $P(x,y)$ is true

a.(∃x∀yP(x,y))⇒(∀y∃xP(x,y))

b.(∀x∃yP(x,y))⇒(∃y∀xP(x,y))

Please someone explain which one is true?
I am confused between these two. It seems to me both are correct. Please clarify.

Comment: The two statements look absolutely identical to me. What's the difference? (And yes, they are both correct.)

Comment: The first is valid, the second not.

Comment: Counterexample for b) : $P(x,y)$ is $<$ and the domain of the interpretation is $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But... the first and second statement are completely identical.

Comment: Can you edit your post?  As it stands the two statements you give are exactly the same.  If you can't clarify the question, I think it should be closed.

Comment: My mistake Mauro! The post has been edited more than once by Dipan, just reverting the texing. I should have noticed that in the last edit there was an actual change in the math! I revert to the "good" version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. is valid, but b. is not.

Just a simple example to illustrate why a. is valid:

Suppose that we are talking about persons, and that $P(x,y)$ means ''x likes y'.

Then $\exists x \forall y P(x,y)$ means that there is a really friendly person: someone who likes everyone! .... let's call this really friendly person 'Bob'.

Now, $\forall y \exists x P(x,y)$ means that everyone is liked by at least one person. Is that true? Yes! Everyone is liked by Bob!

This is of course one possible interpretation, but if you think about, the logic works the same for any interpretation of $P(x,y)$. So, a. is valid.

b. on the other is not valid. Let's take the same interpretation of $P(x,y)$:

$\forall x \exists y P(x,y)$ means that everyone likes at least one person (possibly themselves). OK, does that mean that $\exists y \forall x P(x,y)$, i.e. that there is a super likable person: a person liked by everyone?!  No, maybe all the people are self-centered, and they only like themselves. Assuming there is more than 1 person, then there is no one liked by everyone. So, b. is invalid.